# Focus should come to an applet in the IE when IE becomes as active window

Tags: java, applet

In an applet when opened in Internet Explorer, the focus should come back automatically to the applet instead of going to IE when any window comes over IE and goes back (Internet Explorer again becomes the active window).

To get the focus RequestFocus() and RequestFocusInWindow() are not working for an applet in my case.

Can anyone explain how this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

I can only suppose here. Java can't influence on the environment out of the it's, I don't know exactly how to name it, control area -> you can't influence on IE from an applet.

Comment: As for Window objects like JFrame, JDialog and all you can use window listener to know when this window object becomes as active window. Isn't there such framework for an Applet?

Comment: You can't attach window listener to IE (because it's not in control area of applet) -> you can't make IE to throw a focus on applet.